# Connect to Filemaker Database using JDBC, Python, and JayDeBeApi

Tags: python, linux, jdbc, lambda, jaydebeapi

I'm trying to write an AWS Lambda Python Package that will connect to a FileMaker database over JDBC. To test, I've launched an EC2 instance with the Lambda Linux AMI, and created a virtualenv (/venv) that I'm testing in. I've uploaded the fmjdbc.jar to the instance using WinSCP to /venv/lib/fmjdbc.jar. The code uses JayDeBeApi, following the usage example here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/#usage

My code so far is the following:

```
import jaydebeapi as jdb

driverclass = 'com.filemaker.jdbc.Driver'
jdbcURL = 'jdbc:filemaker://url:port;database'


jar = '/home/ec2-user/lambda-test-project/venv/lib/fmjdbc.jar'
print jar

conn = jdb.connect(driverclass,[jdbcURL,'username','password'],jar)
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/lambda-test-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-package                                               s/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 359, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, jars, libs, *driver_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/lambda-test-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-package                                               s/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 183, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(*driver_args)
jpype._jexception.SQLExceptionPyRaisable: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:filemaker://<MY URL STUFF IS HERE>
```

How can I get the jdbc driver to be read by Python's virtual environment? I'd like to have this code work in a Lambda package eventually, so I'm hoping there's a solution that can be integrated to the Python code that will work repeatedly on newly created servers.

Comment: The [JayDeBeApi documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) says: "If you are using cPython ensure that you have installed [JPype](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JPype1/) properly." Have you done that?

Comment: Hi, any chance if you have any steps or the lambda layers that could be shared if you are able to connect to Informix DB from AWS Lambda Python Environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jpype package to set driver for python. I used it for connecting Oracle DB before. There is my sample code which may be useful for you.

```
import jaydebeapi,jpype

classpath = "your jdbc jar driver path" 

jvm_path = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.36.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so" #your java vm path

jpype.startJVM(jvm_path, "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath) #start jvm based on the driver

conn = jaydebeapi.connect(xxxxxx)
```

Comment: This works, but only for one iteration thought the program. If I try to run the same script again several minutes later, I receive the following error:

`Unable to start JVM at native/common/jp_env.cpp:78`.

Any ideas why this is?